# Identifiying the levels for streams derived from DEM

Tags: grass-gis, dem, hydrology, topography

I am using GRASS GIS and I have been able to identify the various water-flow channels / streams using the documentation from `r.watershed`.

Now I wish to identify the levels of the streams. For example, the "main" stream would have index 1, and the substreams would have index 2 and so on.

Looking for pointers on how to achieve the same ... either on GRASS or QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `r.stream.order` add-on for this: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/r.stream.order.html